# What can I do with old clothes I don't want?

Tags: miitomo

I won a Cat Hood from the Miitomo Drop game, and while it's really neat, I think I'd like to sell it or trade it away if it is possible at all, preferably sell it so I can get some more coins to buy the robot ears I want.

**Is there anything I can do with this old hat to cash in?  Or at least give it to someone who wants it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing you can do with your old clothes at the moment. You can't trade or sell them. Taken directly from [Miitomo's FAQ](https://support.miitomo.com/en-US/faq) :

> - Can I give clothing I've obtained to my friends as a gift?
>
> It is not possible to give items to other users.
>
> - Can I sell clothing or other items I don't want anymore?
>
> It is not possible to sell items.
>
> - Can I exchange clothing items I have for different items in the Miitomo shop?
>
> No, it is not possible to exchange clothing items for different items in the Miitomo shop.